# How do I redirect output of a shell script using Java?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to use Java to execute a shell script in Linux(Ubuntu) and trying to redirect the output to another file.

```
String cmd[] = {"sh", "-c", "my_dir/script.sh > new_dir/out.txt"};
Process pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

However this us not working properly. I am not able to get the output to be stored in the out.txt file.
Could someone suggest a way to do this properly?

Comment: does `new_dir` already exist?

Comment: permission to execute the script?

Comment: @Henry Yes it exists

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). I don't see a need for spawning an extra `sh`. Something like,

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("my_dir/script.sh");
pb.redirectOutput(new File("new_dir/out.txt"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

should be all you need.

Comment: Suppose I want to also print the output of the script file as well at the same time, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @AbhishekGangadhar Your question was how to do the shell redirect. Are you instead asking how to read process output using Java?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch How world I use `tee` command with Process Builder?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
 Use Runtime.exec()

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("my_dir/script.sh > new_dir/out.txt");
    // Wait for execution completion 
    p.waitFor();
```